# I want this dynamic option value in my state React js

Tags: reactjs

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRiC.png)

```
<select className='form-control m-2'>
            <option value="0">select a doctor</option>
            {drData.length === 0 ? <option>No Doctor Available</option>: drData.map((option) => (
              <option value={option.data.uid} onChange={(e)=>setDoctor(e.target.value)} key={option.data.uid}>{option.data.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

Hello I'm using reactjs I want to store this dynamic option value who is comes from firebase in my state variable how I can do this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm understanding your question exactly but if you want to store the result of response, you can try this

```
function Componenet(){
    const [result, setResult]=([]);
    function getDrData = () => {
        // After process you're trying to get drData from database
        if(drData.length !==0){
            drData.map((option) => {
                const newObj = {uid: option.data.uid, name: option.data.name};
                setResult([...result, newObj]));
            } 
        }
    }

    return(
        <ComponentYouWantRender />
    );
}
```